# Find $\mathbb{E}[X(X-1)]$ for the geometric distribution without using derivation

Tags: geometric-series

> I'm trying to find the $\mathbb{E}[X(X+1)]$ for the geometric distribution.

Everywhere I've looked explains how to do it using the derivative but I have not been taught that method. Is there another way to do this? I know that $\mathbb{E}[X(X+1)] = E[X^2]+\mathbb{E}[X]$, but I am unable to calculate $E[X^2]$. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: do you know how $E(X^2)$ relates to the variance?

Comment: yes I do, but after I find $E(X^2)$ I'm expected to find the variance so unfortunately I can't do it backwards like that

Comment: there are two variants of the geometric distribution; what is the smallest value $X$ can take in your case? 0 or 1?

Comment: 1 in this case with the probability distribution = $p(1-p)^[x-1]$

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3398487/proving-variance-of-geometric-distribution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $$\mathbb{E}[X(X+1)]=\mathbb{E}[X^{2}+X]=\mathbb{E}[X^{2}]+\mathbb{E}[X]$$
Now, we know that $$\mathbb{V}ar[X]=\mathbb{E}[X^{2}]-[\mathbb{E}[X]]^{2}$$
Using that, we can see that $$\mathbb{E}[X(X+1)]=\mathbb{V}ar[X]+[\mathbb{E}[X]]^{2}+\mathbb{E}[X]$$
So, since that  $X\sim \textbf{Geometric}(p)$ so, $$\mathbb{E}[X]=\frac{1}{p} \quad \text{and} \quad \mathbb{V}ar[X]=\frac{1-p}{p^{2}}$$

Other approach is by definition, we can see that
$$\mathbb{E}[X(X+1)]=\mathbb{E}[X^{2}+X]=\mathbb{E}[X^{2}]+\mathbb{E}[X]$$
Now, we know that $\mathbb{E}X=\frac{1}{p}$ and we can see that $$\mathbb{E}[X^{2}]=\sum_{x}x^{2}\mathbb{P}[X=x]$$
with $x=1,2,\ldots$ and $\mathbb{P}[X=x]=p(1-p)^{x-1}$.
So, you need to find $$\mathbb{E}[X^{2}]=\sum_{x}x^{2}\mathbb{P}[X=x]=\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}x^{2}p(1-p)^{x-1}$$
Using that $0<p\leq 1$, so we can find that
$$\mathbb{E}[X^{2}]=\sum_{x}x^{2}\mathbb{P}[X=x]=\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}x^{2}p(1-p)^{x-1}=\frac{2-p}{p^{2}}$$

Comment: is there another way to do this if I don't know the variance? I'm expected to calculate it and then use it to find variance

Comment: also, isn't Var(X) = $E(X^2) - (E(X))^2$ ?

Comment: You can say $$E(X(X+1))=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k(k+1)P(X=k)$$ and then find the sum using calculus

Comment: @user229257 Yes, I have a typo. I corrected.

Comment: I've tried that but get stuck when it comes to finding the $ E(X^2)$ part

Comment: @АлександрПальма any tips on how to find$ \sum_{x=1}^{\infty} x^2 p(1-p)^[x-1]$?  That's where I'm running into problems

Comment: @user229257 Try differentiating the geometric series twice to compute the following sum for $|x|<1$: $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k^2 x^k$$

Comment: @user229257 just use the hint of projectilemotion or LinAlg https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3398648/798113